# Ежедневные уведомления на aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x, рассылка

Хочу чтоб бот уведомлял пользователей каждый день в 8 утра, есть бд с всеми айдишниками, только не знаю как прикрутить к боту функцию проверки времени или что то подобное. Как лучше такое реализовать?
Использую aiogram 3.0.0rc2, на вебхуках

Answer (score 2):

Реализовал с помощью apscheduler (apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio.AsyncIOScheduler)

```
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone='Etc/GMT-5')
scheduler.add_job(check_weather, trigger='cron', hour=8, minute=0, kwargs={'bot': bot})
scheduler.start()
```

Где check_weather функция которую он будет вызывать, и аргументами передал словарь с ботом.